# extract email form .msg file

Tags: preg-match-all

I am using mailparse_msg_parse_file to open an msg file and i am trying to extract the send to email.

The msg file for to email has the following pattern:

```
To: "email_address" <email_address>
```

I have tried to get it with preg_match_all width classic email pattern but its not working

The pattern i use is:

```
$pattern="/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/i";
```

and i get all other emails but not them that are inside "" or <>

I have also tried to get anything inside <> but i get also the html tags so it's not really helpful.

Comment: It's been a while since you posted the question.  Do you still need help with this?